# Delete Html entities or replace tag

Tags: node.js, ckeditor, pug

when i display ckeditor text the html tags are also displayed. how can a i show only the text? i'm getting this:

```
<b>Paragraph</b>
```

**Paragraph**

I use Jade template and node.
It's possible to delete  Tag before save in database ? or remove tag after ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution. 
Juste use !{value} instead of #{value} with Jade template to decode html entities.
value contains html entities.

Answer (score 0):

use unescape syntax in the pug file.

```
p
  != 'This code is <strong>not</strong> escaped!'
```

or

```
- var riskyBusiness = "<em>This code is <strong>not</strong> escaped!</em>";
.quote
  p Joel: !{riskyBusiness}
```